# Native Chrome lazyload issue with hidden images

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to use native lazyload (https://css-tricks.com/native-lazy-loading/) in a page with image carousel (slick.js).

In order to avoid displaying all images before the carousel loads, I use to show the first image and after carousel initialization I let them to display based on carousel rules.

Using loading="lazy" attribute cause the carousel container to display bigger than what it should be, inner images (that were hidden before initialization) appear to be resized wrong.
When image become visible the browser resize it correctly and container dimension is adjusted.

With the following code I expect the carousel container to be 250x150, but it is 250x250 until I see all the images inside.
Using inspector I see that image size is **250 x 250 pixels ( intrinsic: 500 x 300 pixels)**.

```
<section class="carousel">
    <img class="first" loading="lazy" src="image500x300.jpg" />
    <img loading="lazy" src="image500x300.jpg" />
    <img loading="lazy" src="image500x300.jpg" />
</section>

<style>
    .carousel { width: 50%; }
    .carousel img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
    .carousel > img { display: none; }
    .carousel > img.first { display: block; }
</style>

<script>
    $('.carousel').slick();
</script>
```

Using infinite carousel option is the worst case because some images are never displayed and container has always wrong dimensions.

It seems that if images are loaded from cache it works correctly, but I'm not completely sure of this.

I replicated it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ygvuzj4/5/

Is there a workaround to avoid this issue?

Thanks

Comment: These sliders usually figure out what height they need to be, by looping over all the slides, and determining the maximum - but that can’t work correctly, if the images aren’t even loaded yet. You could try if explicitly providing `width` and `height` of the images via HTML attributes helps; if not, you might have to specify the target height upfront (if slick allows for that), or wrap these images into a container element each, the height of which you explicitly specify via your CSS then.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I cannot set width/height easily because it is based on screen dimensions.
What I don't unterstand is the fact that it works with custom lazyload plugins (lazysizes for example).
Further, when I inspect image, it is "visible" but outside viewport, chrome in this case is just showing wrong height.